# Is there some scripting language that can compare two similar xml files containing numerical data and generate delta xml?

Tags: xml, xpath, scripting

Is there a scripting language that supports comparing two identical xml files containing numerical data (ex. code coverage xml between two successive test runs) and generate a delta xml with difference?

Comment: Do you want a tool that compares two XML files for differences or a programmatic way to determine the differences?

Comment: Programmatic way since it is intended to be used in automation. The delta values will be further analyzed against thresholds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many you can use, but you would need to consider if there are XML libraries available for the platform or development language to do the job.

Here are some to consider:

- PHP [XMLDiff](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.xmldiff.php)
- Perl [XML::Diff](http://search.cpan.org/~timm/XML-Diff-0.05/Diff.pm)
- C# - [XML Diff API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx)
- Java [XMLUnit](http://www.xmlunit.org/)
- Java [DeltaXML](http://www.deltaxml.com/)
- .NET [DeltaXML](http://www.deltaxml.com/)
- .NET [XMLUnit](http://www.xmlunit.org/)
- MS Windows [ExamXML](http://www.a7soft.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [DeltaXML Core](http://www.deltaxml.com/products/core/) command-line interface for invoking such a comparison from within a script.

In Core, a popular scenario for comparison of numerical data within the XML is to add an XSLT filter to the comparison pipeline (described using XML), this applies declared tolerances for specific XPath locations, e.g.

```
<xsl:template
   match="/weather/deltaxml:attributes/
   dxa:time[
   deltaxml:attribute-in-tolerance(. , xs:double('10.0'))]">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:attribute name="deltaxml:ignore-changes" select="'true'"/>
     <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The [Numerical Tolerances](http://docs.deltaxml.com/core/current/samples/NumericTolerances/ReadMe.html) sample in the DeltaXML documentation describes this more fully.